# isolating css/head/etc in a curl return

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, curl

I am using curl to get an external site. I have it working, but when I show the results, they take over my content. Meaning- it's css effects my webpage, it's z-index's are sometimes higher than mine, etc. I am looking for a way to isolate this website so that it is treated as separate from mine. I want it to work like an iframe where I can control it's z-index and so it's css/javascript does not effect my website at all.

```
<?php
  function fetch_site($base){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    ob_start(); 
      $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
    ob_end_clean(); 

    return $result;
  } 
?>

<div class='myContent'/>
<div class='targetSite'>
    <?php print fetch_site('http://www.....com/'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: So use an iframe, and inject your CSS and JS as needed. Also, watch out for XSS attacks from the site.

Comment: Try the below alternative for Iframe. If you really don't Iframe's in your site

Comment: I need to avoid iframes because, if I understand correctly, one can't call https in an iframe... and this is necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class='myContent'>
<div class='targetSite'>
    <?php // print fetch_site('http://www.google.co.in/'); ?>
    <object data="http://www.example.net/" width="600" height="400">
    <embed src="http://www.example.net/" width="600" height="400"> </embed>
    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This works, but it has the same problem that iframes have-- which is that they cannot load https websites. Is there a way to allow this to support http and https?